# Regex allowing no leading whitespace but allowing anywhere else and requiring at least one uppercase and one lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regex code to validate usernames that have:

- length between 6 and 30
- contain at least one letter from A-Z
- contain at least one digit from 0-9
- not contain a space at the beginning but it might have at
  the end or in the middle.
- may contain special characters

So far I have tried this:

```
^[\S](?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,30}$
```

It works quite good but when I choose an uppercase letter ONLY at the beginning it doesnt validate my password.

```
Test12 34 ----> Doesnt accept but should accept
TesT12 34 ----> Accept 
tesT12 34 ----> Accept
```

Comment: Trying to do this all with a single regex is going to be complex and difficult to maintain - if you can I'd suggest using multiple regexes (or even just straight comparison).

Comment: Please let know if the string like `Tbd dnno here34` should be valid or not.

Comment: Please answer this question above.

Comment: As @DuncanThacker said, don't do this. Checking all requirements one after the other also opens the door for more meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because the `\S` is at the pattern start before the lookaheads. That means, that the lookaheads that require an uppercase ASCII letter and a digit only check them after the first character in string.

Now, there can be two scenarios: 1) there may be any amount of whitespace characters in the string, but at its beginning, 2) only one whitespace char is allowed in the string, and not in the beginning

## Scenario 1

Put `\S` after the lookaheads and decrement the limiting quantifier values to set the limits to 6-30 as `\S` already matches and consumes the first char:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])\S.{5,29}$
                    ^^  ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4K9j5/1).

JS test:

```js
var rx = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])\S.{5,29}$/;
var vals = [ "Test12 34", "TesT12 34", "tesT12 34" ];
for (var s of vals) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

## Scenario 2

Use

```
^(?=.{6,30}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])\S+(?:\s\S*)?$
```

The length is restricted with the positive lookahead at the beginning (`(?=.{6,30}$)`) and the consuming `\S+(?:\s\S*)?` pattern will only allow a single `\s` whitespace (1 or 0 due to the last `?` - *one or zero occurrences* quantifier) and it can be in the middle (as the first `\S` is quantified with `+`, *one or more occurrences* quantifier) or end (as the `\S` after `\s` is `*`-quantified, *zero or more occurrences* quantifier).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4K9j5/3).

Comment: `not contain a space`  I've a feeling only 1 space allowed..  So `Tes t1 234` is passing.

Comment: @Keith That is not deducible from the current pattern and description. Then, it should be [`/^(?=.{6,30}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])\S+(?:\s\S*)?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/k4K9j5/3)

Comment: `That is not deducible from the current description`,   `a space`,  from were I come from means singular.  But nice update to take this into account.  But some clarification from OP won't hurt.. :)

Comment: @Keith "Whitespace" sounds like a collective noun to me.

Comment: Indeed clarification required..  `White Space`, `A Space`,  have 2 different meanings.. You took the subject definition, I took the bullet list.

Comment: @Keith that was exactly what I was looking for, Thanks

Comment: @NimaAzizi What were you after? The solution in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980361/regex-no-white-space-at-beginningbut-allowed-in-the-middle-at-least-one-up/45980423?noredirect=1#comment78920144_45980423), or the solution in the answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the solution in the answer helped me(first scenario)

Comment: @NimaAzizi OK, I added both as people started trolling on me.